# where is attributes section IntelliJ IDEA for android development?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to develop android app. i am not using android studio because my computer is very poor quality so i am gonna use IntelliJ IDEA from now. But i can't find this section called "Attributes". I can see this in android studio but can't find it on IntelliJ IDEA.I have provided two image. one of is android studio and another is IntelliJ IDEA.

[image: Android Studio]

[image: IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: Underneath the XML of the layout, there are two sub-tabs: "Text" and "Design". Click the "Design" sub-tab, so your IDEA setup matches the Android Studio screenshot.

Comment: @harrytenesen Why don't you just use Android Studio for development? IntelliJ includes all functionality of Android Studio so you can assume IntelliJ uses more resources

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException i tried to install but i get every time the gradle error no matter what solution i tried so i switched to intelliJ.